# splitting at a certain point an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I tried using another post's suggestion for splitting at a certain letter / number in the array and there example was.

```
loadednames = [i.split(':', 0) for i in loadednames]
```

I used this in my code as follows

```
checkaccounts = open('accounts.txt', 'r')  
loadedcheckaccounts = checkaccounts.read().split('\n')  
checkaccounts.close()  
print  "These are used for a later variable that works.\n"  
print loadedcheckaccounts  
loadednames = loadedcheckaccounts  
loadednames = [i.split(':', 0) for i in loadednames]  
print "I need these seperated with the name and then the PW after the :.\n"  
print loadednames
```

What I am getting for results are:
['Mike:passwordtest', 'Helga:testmassword', 'Dorathy:testwordspass', '']
I need these seperated with the name and then the PW after the :.

[['Mike:passwordtest'], ['Helga:testmassword'], ['Dorathy:testwordspass'], ['']]
Sorry, there is no character by that name or the password is incorrect. Please try again.
Please enter a name or type 'create' to create a new character.

I need to take the string and seperate the names with their password after the : so I can check the names with another variable. Thanks for any help you can give!

Ah sorry, the accounts.txt is as follows
Mike:passwordtest
Helga:testmassword
Dorathy:testwordspass

Comment: What was in `accounts.txt`?

Comment: Your sample output could not have been produced by the posted code (the `Sorry` stuff at the end, for starters).

Comment: "I need these seperated with the name and then the PW after the :." - I absolutely don't understand what this means: how it's possible to sepArate stuff _with_ something? Totally possible, with a knife, for example, but not in this case... Please clarify.

Comment: i.split(':',0) splits the text 0 times. In other words, not at all.

Comment: i.split(':',0) splits the text 0 times. In other words, not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your results where represented like this;

```
loadednames=['a:b','c:d']

names = [i.split(':')[0] for i in loadednames]
```

names variable will have a list of ['a','c'] which are your names

Answer (score 0):

From `help(str.split)` *If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done.* As mentioned in the comments, you did 0 splits when you really want 1 split. Now you have a list and you want the first item. This can all be squeezed into a couple of lines

```
with open('accounts.txt') as fp:
    loadednames = [line.split(':', 1)[0] for line in fp]
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped too.